# Get attribute values from XML

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Menu TextField="Menu" NavigateUrlField="/#" MenuID="74">
   <Menu TextField="Assets" NavigateUrlField="/Assets" MenuID="1870" />
   <Menu TextField="Asset Category" NavigateUrlField="/AssetCategory" MenuID="1871" />
   <Menu TextField="Asset Location" NavigateUrlField="/AssetLocation" MenuID="1872" />
</Menu>
```

I need to get the TextField and MenuId from this XML. Only from Menu tag that is below root Menu tag.

```
Text Field               MenuId
-------------------------------
Assets                   1870
Asset Category           1871
Asset Location           1872
```

I tried below code but not working:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Menu");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{
    string menuId = elemList[i].Attributes["MenuID"].Value;
    string textField = elemList[i].Attributes["TextField"].Value;
}
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Note `MenuID` in your XML but `MenuId` in your code.

Comment: Thomas, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement menu = doc.Element("Menu");
            var results = menu.Descendants("Menu").Select(x => new {
                textField = (string)x.Attribute("TextField"),
                menuID = (int)x.Attribute("MenuID")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention, to you attribute name "MenuI**D**", not "MenuI**d**"

```
XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = root.SelectNodes("Menu");
for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
{       
    string menuId = elemList[i].Attributes["MenuID"].Value;
    string textField = elemList[i].Attributes["TextField"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Holy cow, only 1 out of 6 answers that explains what is actually wrong and not rewriting the whole code. Keep on doing good work!

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple XPath query to find the `Menu` at parent level and then select all `Menu` nodes below it:

```
XmlNodeList elemList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Menu/Menu");
```

Then also change `Attributes["MenuId"].Value` to `Attributes["MenuID"].Value` because all names are case sensitive in XML.

Comment: Did someone by accident lean on the downvote button? My solution works, I actually tested it, so why?